# Suing of Forced Kidney Transplant

Tags: medical, use-of-force

I watched this video, and this mother, whose daughter needed a kidney transplant, adopted this child. She treated her nicely, but only because she wanted her daughter to get a kidney from the girl who got adopted.

When it was time to transplant, she was practically forced to give her kidney. But a few weeks later, the daughter died. In the video, the adopted girl didn't take any action.

But I was wondering if I were her, could I sue the parent to give back the kidney? It raises questions that I need answers to. If the parent refuses, could I go to court for the kidney?

Comment: sorry if the tag is not related, I couldn't find a good tag

Comment: I don't know if the kidney would still be viable for re-transplant, which makes suing for its return moot. Maybe worth asking on MedSE: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions ?

Comment: just asking if suing for the kidney itself is even legal

Comment: So you're not interested in whether suing for monetary damages could happen here?

Comment: I was just wondering about the legal stuff, not the medical stuff

Comment: Yes, of course she could sue. At least in the US it's perfectly legal to sue anybody for virtually anything. All you need is 20 minutes and the filing fee. That doesn't mean your suit won't be tossed for various reasons or that it won't have repercussions (counter suit), but you can file the suit.